# ArayList as dataProvider for a List: The index 0 is out of range 0

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, arraylist, flex4.5, flex4.6

Does anybody please have an idea, why do I get the runtime error:

```
RangeError: Error #1125: The index 0 is out of range 0.
    ........
    at Popup/update()[Popup.mxml:80]
    at PopupTest/showPopup()[PopupTest.mxml:45]
    at PopupTest/___btn_click()[PopupTest.mxml:52]
```

when calling the function:

```
private function showPopup(event:MouseEvent):void {
    _popup.update(new Array('Pass' , 
        '6♠', '6♣', '6♦', '6♥', '6 x', 
        '7♠', '7♣', '7♦', '7♥', '7 x', 
        '8♠', '8♣', '8♦', '8♥', '8 x', 
        '9♠', '9♣', '9♦', '9♥', '9 x', 
        '10♠', '10♣', '10♦', '10♥', '10 x'), true, 80);
}
```

As if my _list would have no entries at all (but why? I do assign **_data.source=args**) and thus the **_list.ensureIndexIsVisible(0)** call would fail at the line 80:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Panel xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    width="220" height="200"
    initialize="init(event)">   

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

            private static const FORCE:uint = 20;

            [Bindable]
            private var _data:ArrayList = new ArrayList();

            private var _timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 120);

            private function init(event:FlexEvent):void {
                _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerUpdated);
                _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleted);
            }

            public function close():void {
                _timer.reset();
                _data.source = null;
                visible = false;
            }

            private function timerUpdated(event:TimerEvent=null):void {
                var seconds:int = _timer.repeatCount - _timer.currentCount;
                title = 'Your turn! (' + seconds + ')';
                // show panel for cards too
                if (seconds < FORCE)
                    visible = true;
            }

            private function timerCompleted(event:TimerEvent=null):void {
                title = 'Your turn!';
                close();
            }

            public function update(args:Array, bidding:Boolean, seconds:int):void {
                if (seconds <= 0) {
                    close();
                    return;
                }

                // nothing has changed
                if (ObjectUtil.compare(_data.source, args, 0) == 0)
                    return;
                _data.source = args;

                if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
                    close();
                    return;
                }

                if (seconds < FORCE || bidding)
                    visible = true;

                _timer.reset();

                title = 'Your turn! (' + seconds + ')';
                _list.ensureIndexIsVisible(0); // the line 80
                _timer.repeatCount = seconds;
                _timer.start();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup paddingLeft="10" paddingTop="10" paddingRight="10" paddingBottom="10" gap="10" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:List id="_list" dataProvider="{_data}" width="100%" height="100%" fontSize="24" itemRenderer="RedBlack" />
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the reason**

You are adding the new array allright, but then the List starts creating ItemRenderers based on the items that are in that array. This takes some time and happens asynchronously. In the meantime you're saying "show me item 1", but the ItemRenderer for item 1 doesn't exist yet. It will very soon, but not right now. That's why you get an indexoutofrange error.

**the solution**

You have to be sure the List is done creating ItemRenderers before you call that method. The easiest way to solve this situation - though definitely not the cleanest - is to just wait until the next render cycle by using the infamous [callLater()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#callLater%28%29).

```
callLater(_list.ensureIndexIsVisible, [0]);
```

This essentially saying: wait for the next render cycle and then call `ensureIndexIsVisible()` on `_list` with parameter `0`.

(On a side note: if you really only want index 0 this whole thing is rather pointless, because I think a List scrolls back to the top when its dataprovider is changed anyway)

**a cleaner solution**

You can listen on the List for the [RendererExistenceEvent#RENDERER_ADD](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/events/RendererExistenceEvent.html#RENDERER_ADD) event. This will be dispatched whenever a new ItemRenderer was added to the list and it holds a reference to the item's index in the List, the data and the ItemRenderer itself. However in your case we only need the 'index'. Whenever an ItemRenderer is added at index 0 we'll scroll back to the top:

```
_list.addEventListener(RendererExistenceEvent.RENDERER_ADD, onRendererAdded);

private function onRendererAdded(event:RendererExistenceEvent):void {
    if (event.index == 0) myList.ensureIndexIsVisible(0);
}
```

This will immediately scroll to the top when the first ItemRenderer is added and doesn't need to wait until all of them are ready.

Comment: Thanks, **callLater(_list.ensureIndexIsVisible, [0]);** works and also deleting and readding everything too: **_data.removeAll(); for each (var str:String in args) _data.addItem(str);** But isn't there some cleaner way to *kick* the List about the fact that its dataProvider or dataProvider's content has changed?

Comment: Can't I use **_data.itemUpdated()** here?

Comment: The List already knows the data has changed. That's why it starts adding ItemRenderers. What we need to know is when it is done rendering the ItemRenderers. I'll see if I can find the right event for that.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Updated my answer with a cleaner approach.